# How to call QMessageBox Static API outside of a QWidget Sub-Class

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a utility class in my Qt GUI application. However, in my convenience class I wanted to call a `QMessageBox::critical()`, `warning()`, etc. The class isn't a `QWidget`, and therefore I cannot pass `this` as the parent. My class is subclassed from `QObject`, however, so it can run things such as signals and slots. So to work around this--if it's possible to--should I maybe look at the property API instead of using the Static API?

Class declaration:

```
class NetworkManager : public QObject
```

And here's an example of a Static API call that fails:

```
QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Network"), tr("Unable to connect to host.\n"),
QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Discard);
```

So, if I were to build a Property based API message box, would it be possible to call it in a `QObject` somehow? I haven't really used the Property Based API, but I understand from the documentation that it seems to use an event loop (i.e. `exec()`).

Comment: I thought you could pass `nullptr`? The dialog is fixed as application modal anyway for the static convenience methods.

Comment: That's actually an interesting idea. It'd be much easier to do that than use an API I'm unfamiliar with to redo 10+ message boxes :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just pass `NULL` for the first parameter:

```
QMessageBox::critical(NULL, QObject::tr("Error"), QObject::tr("..."));
```

Answer (score 6):

A better way than passing `nullptr` is to use the qobject tree you are already using (assuming that the parent of the NetworkManager instance is a QWidget; adjust the number of parents according to whatever your qobject tree looks like)

```
QMessageBox::critical(qobject_cast<QWidget *> (parent()), "Title", "Message");
```

We use a qobject_cast<> instead of a C or C++ style cast is [because it adds a little protection and will return 0](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) if it can't cast upward to the QWidget *.

If you use `nullptr` the `QMessageBox` will appear as centered over the topmost window (QWidget) rather than the window that actually appeared higher up in the qobject tree of your `NetworkManager` class. This really annoys people who have multiple monitors, lots of windows open, multiple windows from a single application spanning multiple monitors, etc.

Comment: That's a very good idea. However, the NetworkManager is basically used by MainWindow so it should be fine to use nullptr. I'll keep this in mind for the future though.